# custom labels in admin page woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to rename name a label using a custom plugin

WordPress WooCommerce admin product page

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_options_panel' , 'custom_override_fields' );
// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['options_group']['_regular_price_field']['label'] = 'some thing else'; 
    return $fields;
}
```

and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function to change the labels on the product page. Using this custom function hooked in WordPress "gettext" filter hook, you will be able to replace in product page (backend) the text "Regular price" by "List price":

```
add_filter('gettext', 'change_backend_product_regular_price', 100, 3 );
function change_backend_product_regular_price( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( is_admin() && 'woocommerce' === $domain && 'Regular price' === $text  )
    {
        $translated_text =  __( 'List price', $domain );
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

You will set your desired label in below line mentioned in the above function

```
$translated_text =  __( 'List price', $domain );
```